# Command for pasting my command and its output

Tags: command-line, clipboard

Oftentimes I want to post something to a github bug like

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.195.238): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 216.58.195.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=1064.747 ms
```

Right now I run the command, use `screen`'s `C-a C-[` to highlight the area, `enter` to copy it to that buffer, paste it into `vim`, write it to a file and then `cat` that into `pbcopy`. There has to be a better way.

Is there a command I can run which will `tee` the command I type prefixed with a `$` and all the output to `pbcopy`? Or anything close? I envision

```
$ demo ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.195.238): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 216.58.195.238: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=1064.747 ms
^C
$
```

and now the original thing I pasted is in my mac clipboard.

Comment: Is this really specific to OS X?

Comment: Nope. Whatever utility you use to move from a file to a clipboard on other platforms could be substituted for `pbcopy` and it would be the same question.

Comment: Curious: why don't you use the mouse?

Comment: You can leave out the whole vim part. Simply run `pbcopy` and `C-a C-]` to its stdin.

Comment: @hop using the mouse is slow and doesn't work well when there are multiple screens worth of text

Comment: With the mouse, you can click at the start of what you want to copy and shift click at the end. This gets around problems with scrolling the display,etc.

Answer (score 10):

One option is to enable tracing (with `-x`) in a subshell that runs the command. This writes the command to STDERR and the standard output to STDOUT.  Collect both and pipe to `pbcopy`:

```
$ ( set -x; ping -c 3 google.com ) 2>&1 | pbcopy

$ pbpaste
+ ping -c 3 google.com
PING google.com (173.194.217.138): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 173.194.217.138: icmp_seq=0 ttl=44 time=37.436 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.217.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=44 time=38.891 ms
64 bytes from 173.194.217.138: icmp_seq=2 ttl=44 time=39.329 ms
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 37.436/38.552/39.329/0.809 ms
```

Comment: `set -x` is an interesting approach.  Well spotted!

Comment: I'd love to also see my command printed out too (preferably on 2 different streams still), and would like `+` to be `$`

Comment: @PaulTarjan : then change PS4 accordingly. An exemple (not what you need, but shows some possible options) : `PS4='\\$ ${BASH_SOURCE[0]:-inherited}:line ${LINENO}:${FUNCNAME[0]:+${FUNCNAME[0]}(): }  '` . The "\\$" makes "$" the first char, and that char is then repeated to show the level of call. ($ for first level, $$ for second level, etc)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `script` utility to capture the entire interaction including your prompt, command, and its output:

```
script temp.log; cat temp.log | pbcopy
[ do stuff ]
[ end the interaction with ^D or logging out of the shell ]
```

You can then review the file, and its contents will already be on your clipboard.

You can also:

```
script temp.log 'somecommand'; cat temp.log | pbcopy
```

Comment: This is close. It included my whole prompt where I just want a `$ ` and it lets me do many commands where I only want one, and it adds a header and footer I don't want.

Comment: I don't think it can suppress ANSI sequences (as by design it's there to capture the entire session), but you can suppress the header.  Check the man page for `-q`.  You can use `sed` to strip the ANSI codes:  `sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"`

Comment: You can use `script temp.log env PS1='$ ' bash --norc` to get a bash with the prompt you want. Alternatively you can edit your `~/.bashrc` to check for the use of `script` and alter the prompt: `[ $(ps -o command= -p $PPID) = 'script' ] && PS1='$ '`

Answer (score 1):

[iterm2 has shell integration](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) that allows you to select (and auto-copy) the output of the last command with cmd-shift-A.

Answer (score 1):

From your [comment on another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317755/command-for-pasting-my-command-and-its-output#comment558456_317763), you don't want your *entire* prompt to be copied, but only `$`.

How I solve this is simply:

```
16:54:53 [myname mydirectory] 535 $ bash
bash-3.2$ PS1='\$ '
$ echo some command
some command
$ exit
exit
16:57:17 [myname mydirectory] 536 $
```

Easy.  Then I use the mouse to copy and paste the prompt, command, and output that I want.

---

For a different use case where I *just* want the command, not its output and not the prompt, to be able to give someone instructions, I've set up an alias, `zv` (close to "Command V" on the keyboard) to **copy the last command to my clipboard**:

```
alias zv='printf %s "$(history -p \!\!)" | pbcopy'
```

Note the use of `printf` and command substitution to avoid including the trailing newline from `history` into the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

> Right now I run the command, use screen's C-a C-[ to highlight the
>   area, enter to copy it to that buffer,

If you already use `GNU screen` you can copy a selection directly using an external tool.  For example, I added this to `~/.screenrc` on Linux:

```
bind b eval writebuf 'exec /bin/sh -c " xsel -i </tmp/screen-exchange"' 'exec /bin/sh -c "killall xsel"'
```

Now I can mark a selection wih <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>
<kbd>[</kbd>, press <kbd>Space</kbd> and now press
<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> to run `xsel`.  It's not my
idea, it's actually [quite
common](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bind+b+eval+writebuf%22&hl=en).  Note that [some people use it with `pbcopy` instead of `xsel`](https://github.com/bruno-/dotfiles/blob/master/home/.screenrc) so it may work for you without any problems.